# how to solve the overlapping sub problems in Dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, queue, dynamic-programming

Problem statement =>

You are given  queries. Each query consists of a single number N. You can perform any of the 2 operations on  in each move:

1: If we take 2 integers a and b where N=a*b (a>1,b>1), then we can change N=max(a,b).

2: Decrease the value of N by 1.

Determine the minimum number of moves required to reduce the value of N to 0.

here is the link for better understanding.
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/down-to-zero-ii/problem

I know here are some overlapping sub-problems and we can use DP to ignore the computation of same sub-problems again and again.

Now, my question is how in this problem, same sub-problems have same solutions. Because we have to solve this from top to bottom and sub-problem have same solution if we solved them from bottom to top.

For example

```
N=4
1 possibility = 4->3->2->1->0
2 possibility = 4->2->1->0
```

Now in above two possibility, 2 is repeating and I can use DP, but how I store their values. I mean, in 1 possibility solution of 2 is different from 2nd possibility because in first one I've to traverse 4->3->2 here solution of 2 is 2 and in 2nd possibility we traverse 4->2 and solution of 2 here is 1 now these 2 same sub-problems have different values because of the solving from top to bottom. Now I'm totally confused here. Please someone help me out in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for a number N should store the minimun steps required to make it 0
this is how the sol should look

```
int dp[1000001];
memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp);
int sol(N){
if(N == 2){
  return 2;
}
if(dp[n]!=-1){
 return dp[n]'
}
int sol = 1+sol(min(move1,move2));
dp[n] = sol ;
return sol;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2:**

I think this is a solution for your problem. The solution is in JavaScript:

```js
// ****************************************************************************
function findPaths(tree, depth = 0, path = [], paths = [-1, []]) {
  const [node, children] = tree

  path.push(node)

  if (!children) {
    // console.log(path, depth)
    if (paths[0] === -1 || paths[0] > depth) {
      paths[0] = depth
      paths[1] = [paths.length]
    } else if (paths[0] === depth) {
      paths[1].push(paths.length)
    }

    paths.push([...path])
    path.pop()
    return
  }

  children.forEach((el) => {
    findPaths(el, depth + 1, path, paths)
  })

  path.pop()

  return paths
}

// ****************************************************************************
function downToZero(n) {
  const tree = [n]
  const divisors = []

  for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      divisors.push(Math.max(i, n / i))
    }
  }

  if (divisors.length) {
    tree.push(divisors.map(downToZero))
  } else if (n > 0) {
    tree.push([downToZero(n - 1)])
  }

  return tree
}

// ****************************************************************************
function printPaths(paths) {
  console.log('Total number of solutions:', paths.length - 2)
  console.log('Total number of solutions with minimal moves:', paths[1].length)
  console.log('Minimal moves:', paths[0])

  paths[1].forEach((pathIndex) => {
    let printPath = ''

    paths[pathIndex].forEach((element) => {
      printPath = `${printPath}${printPath === '' ? '' : '->'}${element}`
    })
    console.log(printPath)
  })
  console.log('')
}

// ****************************************************************************
// Test
printPaths(findPaths(downToZero(812849)))
printPaths(findPaths(downToZero(100)))
printPaths(findPaths(downToZero(19)))
printPaths(findPaths(downToZero(4)))
```

Comment: Its wrong. Check for the input 812849, your code output is 12 but expected output is 10.

Comment: @Rajatkashyap If this is a good solution, I will add comments to the code.